# Unable to find the correct syntax for creating batch to dump each database into it's own .sql

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have been pouring through multiple forms and stack overflow questions looking for the correct syntax for creating a batch fill that will generate one .sql dump file for each database.

```
:: Name of the database user
set dbuser=user

:: Password for the database user
set dbpass=password

:: Loop through the data structure in the data dir to get the database names

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql" -u%dbuser% -p%dbpass% -e "show databases" ^| FOR /D %%F IN (read databases) DO (

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump" --user=%dbuser% --password=%dbpass% --databases %%F > "D:\Backup\%%F_6am_mon.sql"

)
```

Structure of code mainly came from Jon Lucas at http://kb.hyve.com/wiki/Backup%20All%20MySQL%20Databases%20and%20Output%20To%20Seperate%20Files

I had other code but this one seemed to write to a file.

I've code that works on non-windows, but I need something that will work in windows server 2008 R2 cmd

Can anyone shed some light for me?

ALSO TRIED------------

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%F IN ("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump" -u%user% -p%password% -e "show databases;") DO (

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump" --user=%user% --password=%password% --databases %%F > "D:\Backup\%%F_6am_mon.sql"

)
```

Comment: You are mixing up different concepts. One is a file based iteration through databases with batch tools, the other is a mysql -e script which doesn't know of for /d.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I remove everything but I guess not. I've changed those and removed them from the question as well.

Comment: So how loop through each database available and access the database name?

Comment: Please edit you question to show code as such, mark lines and hit CTRL-K or click on the {} symbol. Both approaches should work, I don't know if your databases are at the location of the above mentioned batch.

Answer (score -1):

If you can install Powershell then this script should work;

```
  foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\Users\jelemans\Documents" -Directory)
  { 
      echo "backing up  - $i.name" 
      $theDate = get-date -format yyyymmdd
      $backupName = "backup$theDate"
      backup($backupName)
  }

  Function backup($dbName)
  {

     $path = "D:backupPath$dbName"
     mysqldump -uxxx -pyyy $dbName > $path
  }
```

witht the correct path set for your db (not my test folder).

Try this script for unix;

```
  for var in "$@"
  do
     echo "Backing up $var"
     backupName=backup$var`date +'%Y%m%d'`

     mysqldump --user=%user% --password=%password% $var > "\Backup\$backupName"

  done
```

with the edits for your user and password.

Execute this to run it from the data directory (or add cd in the script);

```
  find * -type d -exec testScript {} +
```

changing the name of "testScript" to match your script name. Note that this script will try to do mysql as well. you need a mod if you want to skip that one.